# Scrolling menu in iOS

Tags: ios

Basically I'm trying to achieve the look apple has:

[image]

I want the user to be able to make a list and be able to scroll through them similarly to this. However, I want there to be a beginning/end to the list instead of a never ending loop.

This is exactly what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Any ideas on how to even get started with this?

Comment: UIPickerView is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a pickerview to me

http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/

Comment: I feel a little silly now haha. Thank you very much.